# Keep CSS only modal window from jumping to the top of the page

Tags: css, modal-dialog

Is there any way to keep a CSS only modal from jumping to the top of the page?

```
<a href="#modal-1" />MODAL LINK</a>

<div id="modal-1" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="header">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x"/>XX</i></a>
</div>
<div class="copy">
<p>CONTENT GOES HERE</p>
</div>
<div class="cf footer">
</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`

Comment: Then how do you target the modal?